# First view of the question on Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, views

I am just curious about the very first viewer of the question as soon as you post any question. It always show that "viewed 1 time".

Is this like we are the very first viewer of our own question as soon as we post it? Or there is some bot who views your question as soon as you publish it?